# Error 500 in uwsgi routing

Tags: http, url-rewriting, webserver, uwsgi

I'm using uwsgi to provide access to a nested directory structure with "flat" URLs - for example the file `/var/files/f/foo` can be accessed via `http://site/files/foo`. I've accomplished this using `--route "^/files/(.)(.*)\$ static:/var/files/\$1/\$1\$2"`.

This setup works fine when requested files exist, but the server closes the connection and logs a HTTP error 500 when someone requests a nonexistent file. Can it be configured to return something meaningful?

I tried adding `--route "^/files/.* return:404"`, but nothing changed.